# How do you define both a single id and multiple ids with swagger?

Tags: swagger, restify, swagger-2.0

We have the following end point defined in swagger

```
products/{ids}
```

where ids is a list of comma separated ids. However, we get an error if there is only one id. For example `products/4` gives an error whereas `products/4,5` is ok and even `products/4,` is valid.

We are using restify with swagger-restify-mw.

How can you have both `products/4` and `products/4,5` to be valid end points?

Comment: Any luck with this? I only got as far as seeing that swagger completely intercepts all requests so this is mostly not a restify question.

Comment: We ended up accepting the collection as a string and then splitting on the comma.